# SOAP-ENV:Fault in WSDL SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I have created soap web-service,and I am really new to SOAP. While creating a web service, I'm facing the issue below in SoapUI.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 539
Date: Sun, 19 Nov 2023 07:46:34 GMT
Connection: close

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-     ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public com.librarysystem.BorrowBookResponse com.example.sm704_1.LibraryEndpoint.borrowBook(com.librarysystem.BorrowBookRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My SOAP request as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:lib="http://www.librarysystem.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <lib:BorrowBookRequest>
     <member>
        <memberId>12345</memberId>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
     </member>
     <book>
        <bookId>98765</bookId>
        <title>The Great Adventure</title>
        <author>John Smith</author>
     </book>
     <borrowDate>2023-11-20</borrowDate>
  </lib:BorrowBookRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my EndPoint Code:

```
@Endpoint
public class LibraryEndpoint {

private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.librarysystem.com";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "BorrowBookRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public BorrowBookResponse borrowBook(@RequestPayload @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, required = true) BorrowBookRequest request) {
    // Implement your business logic or interact with a repository/service
    BorrowBookResponse response = new BorrowBookResponse();
    response.setMessage("Book borrowed successfully.");
    // Set other response fields as needed
    return response;
}

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ReturnBookRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public ReturnBookResponse returnBook(@RequestPayload @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, required = true) ReturnBookRequest request) {
    // Implement your business logic or interact with a repository/service
    ReturnBookResponse response = new ReturnBookResponse();
    response.setMessage("Book returned successfully.");
    // Set other response fields as needed
    return response;
}

}
```

Here is config file code:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

@Bean(name = "library")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema librarySchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("LibraryPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.librarysystem.com");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(librarySchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}


@Bean
public XsdSchema librarySchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("LibrarySystemSchema.xsd"));
}
}
```

I can successsfully get output of my url **http://localhost:8080/ws/library.wsdl**. However, I got error from SoapUI. ı couldn't understand the error and its cause.

Comment: Error 500 means there was an internal error in the server while processing your request.  You are getting a response so the server is accepting your request.  Your credentials and authentication passed. I also checked you xml request and there is not error nor schema failures in the request.   Every server is different.  So you need to read the server documentation to determine what is wrong. Sometimes checking the server log files will give more info.  Either a http header is wrong or the contents of the body (xml) is wrong.

Comment: I think your URI has an error in the route which is the endpoint.  The route is the path that follows the URI www.librarysystem.com.  The route Error message says : No adapter for endpoint [public com.librarysystem.BorrowBookResponse com.example.sm704_1.LibraryEndpoint.borrowBook(com.librarysystem.BorrowBookRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint.